# Can you use a Nintendo Switch Pro Controller on Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-one, nintendo-switch

I'm fine if it needs to be wired as long as it works.

Answer (score 3):

As I know, NS Pro controller's LZ/RZ were both digital trigger, like a normal button. Compare to xbox one controller's LT/RT, they are analog trigger.

Even if you can connect NS Pro Controller to xbox one via some 3rd party adapter(if exist), you can't provide analog trigger.

Answer (score 2):

No. Despite using same interface (bluetooth), they use entire different messages. Xbox consoles do not have drivers from Nintendo controllers.

Only way this could work is with 3rd party adapter that converts Switch controller messages to Xbox mesages

Comment: Yeah but you can use it wired right

Comment: Um, no. The issue does not go away, that being that two use different drivers to run commands through each others.